# Linking a first library to a second library and the first library to a project

Tags: npm

I have one project and two libraries :

- Project = P
- First lib = L1
- Second lib = L2

P has a dependency to L1 and L1 has a dependency to L2

---

I have a method in L2 that I need to change.
In L1 I call that method.
So in order to test my changes locally I have to link L2 to L1 and L1 to P.

The link between L2 and L1 works as expected, but when I launch 'npm link' on L1 (in order to do later 'npm link L1' on P), the link between the two libs is broken.

Anyone has an idea of the process ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this - are you using `npm link` or `yarn link`? Are you on the latest version of npm/yarn? When you say "the link between the two libs is broken", what do you mean? If I run `npm link` from within L1, it keeps its symlink from `./node_modules/L2 -> ../../L2`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using npm link. My npm version is v12.15.0. In L2, I have added a callback as argument in a 'refresh()' method. After launching 'npm link', when I call the refresh method in L1 , with a function as argument , the linter says that the method expects 0 arguments. So the link is not active anymore.

Comment: Which linter, eslint or typescript? You may need to restart your editor to get it to pick up the new typing. Additionally, if your library is publishing separate .d.ts declaration files, you may need to double-check that they're updated as well. Finally, make sure the typing for L1 are updated to reflect the new typing for the `refresh()` method.

Comment: I succeeded what I wanted. The process is : npm link on L2. npm link on L1. npm link L1 on P. npm link L2 on L1. npx ng build --watch on L2. npx ng build --watch on L1.